# variable has different value then operator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

First time poster, c# beginner.

**Problem:**
Some values result in incorrect calculations, though the operator shows a correct value (when hovering over it in debug)
Variable value should be: 49.9006...
But instead 47.4344... is stored.

[image: Screen shot: Operator value]

[image: Screen shot: double variable value]

**Program:**
Split a spiral into arc segments.
Input: straight line and a curve (curve being a circle or an arc)
Get Arc coordinates, center point & angle.

**Code snippet:** (all variables are defined as doubles, except for i & iNe as these are counters thus defined as int)

```
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        iNe = i + 1;
        if (i == 0)
            nRay = 0;
        else
            nRay = this.RadiusBase / i;
        nRayNe = this.RadiusBase / iNe;
        nAng = this.Alpha * i;
        nAngNe = this.Alpha * iNe;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            cumAng = 0;
            cumAngNe = cumAng + nAngNe;
        }
        else
        {
            cumAng = nAng + cumAng;
            cumAngNe = cumAng + nAngNe;
        }
        nSin = Math.Sin(cumAng);
        nSinNe = Math.Sin(cumAngNe);
        nCos = Math.Cos(cumAng);
        nCosNe = Math.Cos(cumAngNe);
        n1minCos = 1 - nCos;
        nXjonc = nXcp + ((double)iNe * (nXcpNe - nXcp));
        nYjonc = nYcp - ((double)iNe * (nYcp - nYcpNe));
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is your inputs for `nXcp + ((double)iNe * (nXcpNe - nXcp))` calculation exactly?

Comment: Are you sure the nXjonc has been written to at that point? It may be the previous iterations value in the loop

Comment: Set the breakpoint after the line `nXjonc = nXcp + ((double)iNe * (nXcpNe - nXcp));`. Then see. It will be the same.

Comment: Thx Farhan, your comment helped me further, i should have placed breakpoint much closer to problem, the fault was that nXcp, nYcp, nYcpNe & nYcpNe still had to be assigned the new value, so i placed the nXjonc & nYjonc behind that down the line.